# how to Go to a function call in Eclipse Debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Very basic doubt:

If I place a breakpoint inside a function (in DEBUG mode of ECLIPSE), Is there a way to know from where the function is called? This is in reference to java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select Debug Perspective (Window > Open Perspective > Debug) .
If you don't already have Debug view, you can open it from `Window > Open View > Debug`

The debug view should have a call stack that should show how you got to the break point.

[image]

[image]